# Save data in firestore using user uid as document id and be able to retrieve and update it

Tags: javascript, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I'm trying to save data in firestore using user uid as document id and be able to retrieve and update it as well

```
try {
  await createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
    auth,
    email,
    password
  ).then((userCredential) => {
    updateProfile(auth.currentUser, { displayName: username });
    toast.success('Account successfully created');
  
    auth.addDoc.collection("users").doc(userCredential.user.uid).set({
      username: username,
      email: email,
    })
```

Comment: Is there something wrong with the code in the question? Where's to code you're using to retrieve and update the data? Please review the following two guides on asking questions: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and some troubleshooting is a good idea too; step through the code line by line, examining the flow and vars along the way until you find something unexpected

Comment: I'm trying to save the sign up info to firestore using the user uid as the document id, but I get an error saying "Can not read properties of undefined 'collection' "

Comment: What is this `auth.addDoc.collection`? Auth doesn't have an addDoc function and I am pretty sure that's not the correct implementation of addDoc as well. Take a look at the Firebase Getting Started Guide [Set a Document](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/manage-data/add-data#set_a_document)

Answer (score 0):

used setDoc

```
   setDoc(doc(db, "users", userCredential.user.uid), {
              username: username,
              email: email,

              })
```